# Regex in javascript to get a tab and it's content

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following html template as a string in JS:

```
Hello
<repeater>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-33"><img src="{{col1}}" /></div>
        <div class="col col-33">{{col2}}</div>
        <div class="col col-33">{{col3}}</div>
    </div>
</repeater>
World!
```

I would like to write some regex that will return the  tag and it content (may be more then one repeater on the page) so the result would be something like this:

```
<repeater>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-33"><img src="{{col1}}" /></div>
        <div class="col col-33">{{col2}}</div>
        <div class="col col-33">{{col3}}</div>
    </div>
</repeater>
```

can't find any working example anywhere and can't figure it out. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

As suggested in an answer below - I tried this:

```
var myRe = new RegExp("<repeater>([\s\S]*?)<\/repeater>", "i");
var myArray = myRe.exec(html);
```

myArray returns null object.

Comment: Are you aware of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/113195? How about feeding the thing in a `document.createDocumentFragment()` and using DOM methods?

Comment: @Boldewyn - as I mentioned above - it a string. that string is html tags but still a string.

Comment: So what? You always ever parse strings with regexes. It's just when the strings contain HTML/XML, and you want to _gain knowledge_ of that markup by means of a regex, that this is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @developer82 have you checked my answer ?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) on `Regexp.exec`. When the expression fails, `null` is returned.

Comment: see selected answer - it is possible!

Comment: It is possible *in some special cases*. It is not possible reliably in all valid appearances. Think for once of nested `<repeater>` elements. What will your regex match?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I've done the best I could. Good luck anyway. https://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: and i highly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'Hello\n<repeater>\n    <div class="row">\n        <div class="col col-33"><img src="{{col1}}" /></div>\n        <div class="col col-33">{{col2}}</div>\n        <div class="col col-33">{{col3}}</div>\n    </div>\n</repeater>\nWorld! somethingg else <repeater> <div>here some test </div></repeater>'
var res = str.match(/<repeater>([\s\S]*?)<\/repeater>/g);
console.log(res);
```

check this, you will get the array of values matched

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse html with regexs; it will be a pain/impossible. For your particular example I think `<repeater>([\s\S]*?)<\/repeater>` would do (http://rubular.com/r/E6muRIWaGN) but you would be better off using an html parser and working on the resulting tree (since `<repeater>` is valid html syntax).

Comment: use a lazy one, that will be correct <repeater>([\s\S]*?)<\/repeater>

Comment: Thanks. on the site you referred it seems to work, but not on my code. Please see my edit above.

Comment: @developer82 Not sure why it doesn't work with the RegExp constructor; use a literal (better performance too): `var pattern = /<repeater>([\s\S]*?)<\/repeater>/gi`

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard DOM methods, that are way more reliable. I've put together a [small JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/boldewyn/BBgfw/). It works like this:

```
/* assuming var tpl to hold the string */
var frag = document.createElement('div');
frag.innerHTML = tpl;

var repeaterElement = frag.querySelector('repeater');
var string = repeaterElement.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned - it's a string of html - it's not on the dom.

Comment: Then feed it in the DOM. Have you evaluated the JSFiddle (working example)?

Comment: It will never appear in the document. The created `div` is completely detached from it. (You would need something like `document.body.appendChild(frag)` beforehand.)

Comment: @Boldewyn bro its okay